# Does youtube have a limit of video search result?

Tags: youtube

I heard that youtube API has a limit of searching result(about 500 videos) but searching on youtube has no limit.

So, I am trying to get all of the result of some keywords but it seems that there is a limit on searching youtube too.

For example, I think 'league of legends' keyword will have more than 1000 videos but when I searched with that keyword on youtube, The number of videos was about 800.

Does youtube have a limit of video search result? If it has, is there any way that I can get unlimited result?

Comment: `is there any way that I can get unlimited result?` - havent tried, honestly, but you can consider use Google Custom Search API and filter the search for get results from YouTube.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave That would be a good way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another option that might be more suitable for your needs is [Google Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/cse/list). With GCS, you can set the API for filter the results from a given website - in this case, from YouTube.